# Banach separate theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I recently read some papers about the Banach separate theorem for geometry version:[image]

I can prove U is convex easily, but I get to struggle with claim the open and contain the zero vector, I have tried to prove by for every point must have a neighborhood for open property already, but I cannot get an idea, also, and why it contains 0
please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo. See Theorem 3.4 in Rudin's FA. You are supposed to take $x_0=w_0-v_0$ instead of $v_0-w_0$. Once you do this it is clear that $0 =v_0-w_0+x_0 \in U$.

$U=\bigcup_{w \in W} (V-w+x_0)$ and translates of open sets as well as union of open sets is open.

Comment: brilliant, thank you very much

Comment: but why it contains a zero vector, does it by without loss of generality?

Comment: There is a typo. See Theorem 3.4 in Rudin's FA. You are supposed to take $x_0=w_0-v_0$ instead of $v_0-w_0$. Once you do this it is clear that $0 =v_0-w_0+x_0 \in U$. @RiYang

Comment: I originally thought that, thank you very much, twice

Comment: @RiYang If you are satisfied with the answer you can consider approving it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Otherwise this will continue to be listed as an unanswered question.